# Can I modify or delete one of my steam friends group tags?

Tags: steam

In Steam friends, you can organize your friends by "tagging" them (in your friends list, right click someone and select "Tag as").  It's convenient since it allows you to organize your contacts following the games you play together, the moment of the day when they are available, whatever.

[image: Steam friends group tags]

But once you have created a tag an assigned it to some of your friends, is it possible to

- modify the tag (rename it) ?
- delete the tag (and, hence, untag all the tagged friends) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far, it sounds like it's a missing feature.

> Tagging seems to be working just like game categories, so no editing unfortunately.
>   [Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2048837#3)

It's not possible to modify a tag, and the only way to delete it is to untag everyone.

> Just untag all the friends from the group you want to remove, and the group will disappear (once it has no friends listed).
>   [Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2048837#6)

Comment: I untagged everyone and tag still exists. :( Didn't anyone find a hackish solution with editing steam config files?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to immediately rename the tag itself.

I believe the easiest option is to create a new tag and tag all the users of your previous tag, then untag your friends from the old tag.

I don't think there is a way to select multiple friends at once.

Probably it's just wishful thinking but maybe you can edit tags in one of the steam files. I an **NOT SURE** if this is actually possible though. A quick glance through the files doesn't show anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is this:

Go into the group/tag you want to disable, Then just click the "Tag As" on the members and uncheck them. When a tag has no users, it disappears from the list.

Comment: This answer has been given already. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131855/15726